Ubuntu 24.04 installation window contents cut of
I have a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro with an display of 2560×1600 pixels. I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 on different SSDs. I wanted to upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 by doing a fresh install (German Installation manager) onto the old system. I have different partitions for / and /home.
During the installation process when I have to configure the partitions the option to choose whether the partition will be formatted or not is cut of. The window cannot be resized and I cannot scroll vertically.

Possible solution:
I changed the Language to english, so the entries were shorter and did fit on the screen. This works, but only for people who understand english well enought.

Sounds like a bug.

I encountered different issues while installing. I couldn’t type in computer name or it randomly quit the install sequence.
You may try Ubuntu (Safe Graphics) which finally let me install it properly. I’m working with fairly new PC hardware in terms of CPU & GPU.
